# Cross-Site Request Forgery(CSRF) Protection in TYPO3

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

In my case, I would like to use CSRF, Cross-Site Request Forgery in typo3 extbase version 7.6.11 but I am not sure how to implement it. Could you guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormProtection/Index.html) on this topic?

You can use the FormProtection classes to do that.